# Redirect domain to 404 generic page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, web-hosting

I have my website (a.com). Another person is pointing your domain (b.com) to my server. That is wrong.

Is it possible to redirect all traffic that comes from b.com for a generic 404 page? think this is possible with a file htaccess

Thanks you!

*Edit*

i can do this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.b.com/$1 [R=404,L]
```

**or**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.b.com [nocase]
RedirectMatch 404 ^(.*)
```

Comment: thank you for your answers, I do not want a specific page like 404.html or something.html. I'm looking for something more generic as the server or not found (no html). Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

**UPDATE**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^domainb\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*  - [R=404]
```

You could also try a general forbidden error, like this:

```
order allow,deny
deny from b.com
allow from all
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} b\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /404.html [R=404,L]
```

This will check if traffic is coming from `b.com` and if yes then it will redirect all the requests to a generic `404.html` page.

Answer (score 0):

How I did it was to put this code in the htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule .* /index.html [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

Which send the request to the index.html file. Then use the refresh function in html to redirect the file to the desired domain:

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
   <title></title>
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=https://www.mydomain.co.uk/">
 </head>
 <body>


 </body>
</html>
```